# cancelAllLocalNotifications With Multiple LocalNotifications

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have a scenario where I schedule two separate LocalNotifications.  One is set to fire at ten past midnight and the other fires every hour.  I can distinguish between them by setting the UserInfo for the notification when I am scheduling it.

For the hourly notification I create an item in Core Data each time that notification fires.  But the problem is that for the hourly notification I am getting a lot of extra items in Core Data each time it fires.

I am NOT calling the following line of code because calling it it seems to also cancel my notification that is supposed to fire after midnight.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

How should I use cancelAllLocalNotifications when I have multiple scheduled LocalNotifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as you see. `cancelAllLocalNotifications`, as it's name suggests, will cancel everything. Yes, also, you should use the `userInfo` to differentiate between your notifications.

To manage / remove your notifications selectively you should get all of the registered notifications with `scheduledLocalNotifications`, then iterate over them checking the `userInfo`, then call `cancelLocalNotification` with the ones you no longer need.

Comment: exactly the explanation I needed. Google has been failing me!

Answer (score 1):

Since **Swift 3.x** took place, this is the code necessary to remove all local push notifications:

```
let notificationCenter : UNUserNotificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
notificationCenter.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
notificationCenter.removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
```